# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 - Maintain model state

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Am new to ASP.NET MVC 3.0. Request expert's view on the below mentioned scenario.

I have a customer details page, where only Name is editable. There are 10 other customer properties that are non editable and displayed using SPAN. When user submits the page, I need to update only the Name.

If am using EF, I will have to load customer again, overwrite name and then save. Otherwise I will have to maintain customer model somewhere.

Anyone tried caching model (or viewmodel) using session id? Is it a good practice?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Let me try to be more descriptive: I have a customer details view, which displays a customer record, with only Name as editable. There are other customer details like email, phone etc which are non editable and displayed in view using span. When user edits name and submits the page, model tries to update details of customer in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost thinking in right direction.

*If am using EF, I will have to load customer again, overwrite name and then save. Otherwise I will have to maintain customer model somewhere.*

> In Update Method **Load Customer again and update name Only as required and then save

**For 2 reasons

1. [The first and most important rule is 'don't trust user data'.](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=do%20not%20trust%20on%20web%20input&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=uKb&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=Do%20Not%20Trust%20User%20Input%20Directly%20MVC&pbx=1&oq=Do%20Not%20Trust%20User%20Input%20Directly%20MVC&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=21386l22857l0l23030l5l5l0l0l0l0l446l1383l2-1.2.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=bc4858d1c8f16f2a&biw=1024&bih=578) and
2. Concurrency and to avoid saving old data. [See this example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Instead of using Session, I will suggest to use Hidden Field for record LastUpdateDateTime and Customer ID which will be posted back in the model to retrieve record and verify LastUpdatedtime with database record

Answer (score 0):

Tipically, you should use a view model different than the database model. Having said that,in your current case the situation is very simple, submit only the name to the controller and then set the Name property of the object you get from EF with the submitted name.

Caching the view model or the model isn't your concern. The database model caching is handled by EF, your problem is mainly a lack of clear application layering. IN fact I strongly suggest to learn a bit more about the MVC pattern, basic application architecture (2-3 layering) and when and how to use a OR\M (which EF is).

Answer (score 0):

use hidden inputs for other properties in your form. In that way you can get all properties binded to your EF entity and you dont need to get entity again from db.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.x)
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.x)
```

or you can serialize the entity(if you use POCO entities) and set to hidden input. When you post back you should deserialize the entity.

My choice is always first one. :)